# Python and nfqueue errorerror during nfq_create_queue()

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am trying to run the following code.

```
def main():

    global action, inputprotocol, actiontype, inputportnum, inputipaddr

    actiontype = "ipaddress"
    action = "accept"
    inputportnum = ""

    q = nfqueue.queue()
    q.open()
    q.bind(socket.AF_INET)
    q.set_callback(cb)
    q.create_queue(0)

    try:
        q.try_run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
        print ("Interrupted")

    print ("unbind")
    q.unbind(AF_INET)
    print ("close")
    q.close()

main()
```

Each time I try to run this Program, I am getting RuntimeError: error during nfq_create_queue().
I tried running it under sudo, also checked whether same script is already running or not but not getting any output.
What should I do?

Comment: Can you please post the full Traceback?